# Cannot login to sql server 2008 R2 after rebooting server

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using Windows-server-2008 with Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

And there are a lot of questions about this, but nothing on the internet solved it.
The problem is that i can't connect to the my SQL Server 2008 R2 after rebooting my server.
I placed some new memory in my server, and after rebooting my client/server application didn't work anymore because it cannot reach the database.
So i tried to get in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), and tried to loggin with Administrator and another user but both do not work.

When i logg in the following message is displayed:

> Cannot connect to (local)
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection
> to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
> name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
> (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
> (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

I Tried a lot of different things like:

- Rebooting server
- Try to start the server manually from Sql Server Configuration Manager
- Named Pipes - Enabled
- TCP/IP - Enabled
- Tried to create an new system user or database user as described in the following article: [Click Here](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/115/posts/11143/how-to-access-a-newly-installed-sql-server-2008-r2-instance-if-you-do-not-know-the-login-and-passwor.aspx)

Can somebody please help me? I am really confused because i need to get this online. Otherwise i have to reinstall the database server but i do not have a back-up. (is there some folder with a back-up of the settings/tables/columns are stored and can be imported from reinstall?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the exact same problem. net start mssqlserver was giving me the blurb about a failed login attempt. The problem was that I had recently changed the password for the administrator account, and the new password didn't get updated in services.

Here's how I fixed it:

First locate SQL Server from the list here:

[image]

Right click and select properties, and navigate to the Log On tab:

[image]

Then I typed the new password, and like magic I was able to start SQL Server right through the services manager.

I also did this for any other processes which were marked as "stopped" even though Startup Type was marked as "automatic" (namely, SQL Server Agent).

Answer (score 1):

Is it a named instance or default?  Also, is this a local instance?  (I see the "(local)" but just wanted to make sure.)

Comment: Well i don't know how to check that, but as i remember i just logged in with my Administrator, created a database named: 'baalzebubS43' and created an member: 'baalzebubmanager' that had the permissions to acces this database with SQL Server Authentication. The admin acces the database with Windows Authentication. and yes it's local as long as i remember the times i logged in.

Comment: It sounds like it isn't started.  Go to command prompt and type "net start mssqlserver"

Comment: I opened CMD and typed: "net start mssqlserver" and it says: SystemError 1069, (translated from dutch to english:) the service is not started because of a failed loggin attempt.

Comment: Try "net stop mssqlserver", then do net start.  If that doesn't do it, reboot the box.

Comment: net stop mssqlserver says the server isn't even running. And i rebooted my server a couple of times.

Comment: Hmmmmmmm, this is odd.  I assume that whatever windows account you're using is set up in SQL server.  I was able to find this article on the error: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259733

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11709/discussion-between-kris-gruttemeyer-and-daniel-martinus)

Answer (score 0):

Start the sql server services from services.msc and try to connect